# Android studio ucanacess: given file doesnt exist error

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

im using ucancess 2.0.9.2 in android studio 2022

im trying to write to an access table but for some reason I cant even make the connection.

the error I'm getting:
I/System.out: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: given file does not exist: C:/Users/XXORX/Desktop/try/test.accdb

here's the code:

```
Connection con; // for connecting to DB
                Statement stmt; // for running query
                String str;

                try {
                    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                    String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://E:\\Database2.accdb";
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                    stmt = con.createStatement(); // Create statement

                    // for creating table
                    str = "CREATE  TABLE  ALBUMS (Title  VARCHAR(50), Performer  VARCHAR(50), Price  DOUBLE )";

                    // execute query
                    stmt.executeUpdate(str);

                    str = "INSERT  INTO  ALBUMS  VALUES ('Let It Be' , 'Beatles', 60 )";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(str);

                    str = "INSERT  INTO  ALBUMS  VALUES ( 'Imagine' , 'John Lennon', 50 )";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(str);

                    str = "INSERT  INTO  ALBUMS  VALUES ('The Wall' , 'Pink Floyd', 55 )";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(str);

                    stmt.close(); // Close connection
                    con.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
```